# IntegrityError at /register/ NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.description

Tags: python, django, apache2

I'm in the last stages of deploying my django application onto a web server, but recently have been getting this error when trying to register a new user `IntegrityError at /register/ NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.description`

I re-ran the error with DEBUG turned on and it says that the direct cause of the problem is in line 17 in the register section of my views.py file, which looks like this:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit= False)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        is_teacher = form.cleaned_data.get('is_teacher')
        if is_teacher == True:
            user.is_staff = True
            user.save() *LINE 17*
        else:
            user.is_staff = False
            user.save() 
        messages.success(request, f'Tu cuenta se ha creado correctamente, ahora puedes iniciar sesión')
        return redirect('login')

else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Users Forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(
    label= 'Correo Electrónico',
    required=True,
)

username = forms.CharField(
    max_length=100, 
    required=True,
    label='Nombre de Usuario'
)

password1 = forms.CharField(
    label = "Contraseña",
    required=True
)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label = "Confirmar Contraseña",
    required=True,
)

is_teacher = forms.BooleanField(
    label='Soy profesor/a',
    required=False,
)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_teacher']
```

Users models.py

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
"""
An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
admin-compliant permissions.

Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
"""
username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

username = models.CharField(
    _('username'),  
    max_length=150,
    unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
    validators=[username_validator],
    error_messages={
        'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
    },
)
first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
description = models.CharField(_('About me'), max_length=600, blank=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(
    _('staff status'),
    default=False,
    help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
)
is_active = models.BooleanField(
    _('active'),
    default=True,
    help_text=_(
        'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
        'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
    ),
)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

objects = UserManager()

EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')
    abstract = True
```

The problem is that I don't understand why it's saying that's the problem, since I had tested that feature many times in my local server. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your User model and form to the question? Looks like you have a `description` field which is non-nullable on the model but is not required by the form

Comment: @IainShelvington Yeah no problem, I have edited my post just now so that you can see it

Comment: You shared your `Profile` model not your `User` model?

Comment: @IainShelvington so sorry for that. I use the default user model that comes with django. Check again, I have added it

Comment: The built-in User model does not have a `description` field, which version of Django are you using and where did you get the User model from?

Comment: I added that a while ago for another django project I have, but it wasn't creating any issues. But that is the default user model.

Comment: should i just get rid of it then?

Comment: You modified the model in the downloaded package in site-packages?  Yes you should revert all changes you made to Django

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks for your feedback, I have deleted all the modifications and even ran a new clean installation of django on the machine, however I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Looks like you also created and applied some migrations from the auth app, is dropping and recreating the entire database an option? Did you delete the migration files that you created in the auth app too?